# .htaccess for a WordPress website, utilizing a redirect

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

Following this article: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/limit-access-login-page/

I have included the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /path-to-your-site/index.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 403 /path-to-your-site/index.php?error=404

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)?your-site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

My website's URL does include the "www" portion, therefore is it safe/okay to include the "www" for the following line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)?www.your-site.com [NC]
```

I'm not very familiar with editing the .htaccess document, I appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only allow `www` site your this directive:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://www\.your-site\.com/ [NC]
```

This will also allow `https` protocol.

Comment: Great, I did actually need the https portion. Thank you

Comment: Can you please tell me what this means: (.*)

Comment: I didn't use `.*` in my regex as that's not really needed. `.*` means match anything of any length.

Comment: Cool, yes it's working, thank you! Safe to continue to use .* for the other lines?

Comment: Yes it is safe to use rewrite rules.